# Slow query performance with exported/imported database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

Within a SQL Server Express installation I get a high query execution time with a database. The database structure and data comes from 2 different sources. One source is an own created database(database A) structure for an application, with an own database scheme. The other source is an export of another database(database B).

For importing the data from the other database, I restore the database B from a file to a temporary database within the SQL Express Istance and from this I copy the data by a script to database A. The script copies all the data, even with indexes.

When I run queries on the temporary database and the database b, there is a huge performance difference.

Queries which take 10 seconds on the temporary database, take 10 minutes on database b.

When I export the database with the SQL Management Studio to the same instance, the same problems occurs, so i assume the problem in not in the srcript.

What can cause these performance differences?

Comment: Statistics differences?

Answer (score 1):

try to execute the same query on both databases with this litle code before

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;

[YOUR QUERY]
```

and with the actual query plan option checked (see picture below).

[image: Query Plan]

Then compare the two results

[image: Message-ExecutionPlan]

Are they the same ?

Comment: The results are different. Very noticable is the amount of RAM which is used for both runs. 1 used 70MB and the other one around 456MB, which is the faster one. But what can be the reason for that, or which indicators needs to be checked?

Comment: looks at properties of your sql server (in management studio right clic on sql instance -> Properties), go in memory and looks to Minimum server memory and Maximum server memory